# Debian console size in VirtualBox

Tags: debian, virtualbox

I installed Debian 7.2.0 as a guest operating system on VirtualBox 4.2.18 (host OS is Windows 7). I installed Debian without any graphical user interface. When I start up Debian, the console size is awfully small (about 80x40). How could I change that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The resolution of virtual consoles can be set by adding the following lines to `/etc/default/grub` and then running `update-grub` (maybe as root):

```
GRUB_GFXMODE=1024x768x32
GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep
```

Just change the `1024x768` to the resolution you want.

Comment: Thanks Risto for your reply. With slight modifications, and with the help of http://askubuntu.com/questions/18444/how-do-i-increase-console-mode-resolution I was able to solve my problem.

Comment: Glad to hear that you solved the problem!

Comment: doesn't work in debian 8.2 jessie on VMWare Workstation 12

Comment: Is there a way to do this without GRUB? As in, not taking GRUB into account -- when the system has already been booted?